# Howto get any item (Point, LineString, Polygon) within a bounding box in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I've a problem with a query matching items inside a BoundingBox.
How it's possible to match all items of  type `2dsphere` (GEO JSON)?
In this case I only got the data of type `Point` but the items of type `LineString` won't appear inside the result.

The schema definition looks like the following example:

```
/**
 * Media location values (Point, LineString, Polygon)
 * @property location
 * @type {Object}
 */
 location:{
      "type":Object,
      "index":"2dsphere"
 },
```

I've e.g. this items in it:

```
[

    {
        "_account": "52796da308d618090b000001",
        "_id": "5284e5798a1c039735000001",
        "location": {
            "coordinates": [
                8.663705555555556,
                50.10165277777778
            ],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "name": "Foto.JPG",
        "preview": "/img/thumbs/13719-3zavxm.JPG",
        "type": "image/jpeg",
        "added": "2013-11-14T15:00:09.113Z",
        "latlng": [ ],
        "shares": [ ],
        "shared": false,
        "tags": [ ]
    },
    {
        "_account": "52796da308d618090b000001",
        "name": "Filtererd_Track.kml",
        "type": "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml",
        "_id": "5284e5c48a1c039735000002",
        "added": "2013-11-14T15:01:24.280Z",
        "latlng": [ ],
        "shares": [ ],
        "shared": false,
        "tags": [ ]
    },
    {
        "_account": "52796da308d618090b000001",
        "_id": "5284e5c48a1c039735000003",
        "location": {
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    9.49653,
                    50.94791
                ],
                [
                    9.49731,
                    50.94811
                ],
                [
                    9.49744,
                    50.94812
                ],
                [
                    9.49755,
                    50.94808
                ],
                [
                    9.4991,
                    50.94579
                ],
                [
                    9.49969,
                    50.94545
                ],
                [
                    9.50037,
                    50.94525
                ],
                [
                    9.50136,
                    50.9452
                ],
                [
                    9.50851,
                    50.98557
                ]
            ],
            "type": "LineString"
        },
        "name": "test 2.gpx",
        "preview": "/img/thumbs/13719-14rvt8w.png",
        "type": "application/gpx+xml",
        "added": "2013-11-14T15:01:24.529Z",
        "latlng": [ ],
        "shares": [ ],
        "shared": false,
        "tags": [ ]
    }

]
```

The query to fetch the items looks like the following example but it does not match `LineStrings` / `Polygons`....
Think it's because of the subarrays but don't know how to include this in the query.

```
{
    {
        "location": {
            "$geoWithin": {
                "$box": [
                    [
                        -39.375,
                        36.73888412439431
                    ],
                    [
                        76.640625,
                        56.897003921272606
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? Do you have an index on location?

Comment: I'm using the latest version 2.4.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to get everything in a bounding box by using `$geoIntersects` and create a Polygon from Bounding Box.
Like example below.

```
    {
    "location": {
        "$geoIntersects": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            5.372314453125,
                            52.288322586002984
                        ],
                        [
                            12.623291015625,
                            52.288322586002984
                        ],
                        [
                            12.623291015625,
                            49.67829251994456
                        ],
                        [
                            5.372314453125,
                            49.67829251994456
                        ],
                        [
                            5.372314453125,
                            52.288322586002984
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Interesting that $polygon and $geometry: {type: Polygon...} are subtly different. The first (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/polygon/) completes the polygon (last assumed to connect to the first) and the GeoJson requires a closed LineString, last and first must match (http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linestring)

Comment: I had the same problem, I found the same solution. And I am also interested for a better solution :-)

Comment: Furthermore, I found that $polygon operator does not query against LineString (in my case), it only outputs the Point type data in the collection. I ended up using $geometry operator which results LineString and Point types. Very much like the answer above.