# Query returns wrong result

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, 2dsphere

I've stuck with a problem of matching items inside a polygon (simple box). I can't figure out why the item which is inside the queried box is not resulting. So here what i have:

```
>db.testing.getIndexes();
{
    "0" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "test.testing",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    "1" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "point" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "ns" : "test.testing",
        "name" : "2dsphere_index"
    }
}
```

Here is my documents (i've tested different formats):

```
>db.testing.find();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5439c9c61120c95f4c50a369"),
    "point" : {
        "lng" : -80.087535,
        "lat" : 42.054246
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5439cc6d1120c95f4c50a36a"),
    "point" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -80.087535,
            42.054246
        ]
    }
}
```

And here is query:

```
>db.testing.find({"point": {"$geoWithin": {
    "$geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-80.267831,42.050312],
            [-80.267831,45.003652],
            [-73.362579,45.003652],
            [-73.362579,42.050312],
            [-80.267831,42.050312]
          ]
        ]
      }
}}})
```

But the problem is that it returns zero results!
If you not sure, that point is really in square, than copy this:

```
{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.087535,42.054246]},{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-80.267831,42.050312],[-80.267831,45.003652],[-73.362579,45.003652],[-73.362579,42.050312],[-80.267831,42.050312]]]}]}
```

and check it [here](http://geojsonlint.com/).

I'm confused, could somebody help me with this please?
Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
Also, those points is got found when we decrease polygon area, for example, to:

```
[[-80.159937,42.050312],[-80.05204,42.050312],[-80.05204,42.09646],[-80.159937,42.09646],[-80.159937,42.050312]]
```

If it's needed i could provide like 100 of such points. For example one more strange point:

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-76.537071,42.058731]}
```

**Update:**
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By1thKMatgVybUY4UUk2YW05bWc/view?usp=sharing) is a file with points collection dump (around 700 points).

Comment: How about remove the last repeated coordinate array because I remember in mongodb it will automatically link the first And last coordinate node.

Comment: Nope, it causes an error: `"$err" : "can't parse query (2dsphere): ...".` Look at Alan's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981372/howto-get-any-item-point-linestring-polygon-within-a-bounding-box-in-mongodb?rq=1#comment30190415_20181336)

Comment: That is really odd. I tested another point that is more obviously inside, db.testing.insert({"point":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[-76,43]}}), and this was returned by the query. However, I also tested your original point and polygon in Postgis, using ST_Contains and, of course, it returns true. Sorry, I have no answer, just confirm what you have found and no idea why.

Comment: If you could provide more sample points that fail, and shouldn't, it would be useful.

Comment: I've added file with dump at the end of the post.

Comment: I confirm this on MongoDB 2.6.5 as well. Could you [file a SERVER ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) on the MongoDB JIRA and link to it from here? Thanks!

Comment: I've already done it yesterday:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB (2d sphere index) uses [Geodesic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) to build polygons, which means the shortest line between two points.

This is how it looks on sphere:
[image: Explanation on sphere]

And this is how it looks on plain:
[image: Explanation on plain]

Zoomed in image shows that point really not in square:
[image: Explanation on plain zoomed in]

Comment: In my case (polygon = box) I've used simple comparison query:
box.lat1 <= point.lat <= box.lat2 and
box.lng1 <= point.lng <= box.lng2